# Extracting similar XML tag values with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, xml, beautifulsoup

**Let's assume i have the following xml data:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckAccountReturn>
<returnCode>0</returnCode>
<errorCode/><errorLabel/>
<subscriberFound>1</subscriberFound>
<idBase>Myandev</idBase>
<numSubscriber>2293803</numSubscriber>
<numContrat>1</numContrat>
<accountRef/>
<currency>KYAT</currency>
<tokenId>9d5f4127a2d0a1b9f9ff6926ac6a73b94d58dc3e82</tokenId>
<offersList>
<offer>
<code>RACCS19|RACCS19</code>
<label>Renew Shall DTH 2019</label>
<durationsList>
<duration><code>1</code>
<label>01 Months</label>
</duration>
<duration><code>12</code>
<label>12 Months</label>
</duration>
<duration><code>3</code>
<label>03 Months</label>
</duration><duration>
<code>6</code>
<label>06 Months</label>
</duration></durationsList>
<optionsList/></offer>
<offer><code>RBASS18|RBASS18</code>
<label>Renew Htoo Shall DTH 2019
</label><durationsList>
<duration><code>1</code>
<label>01 Months</label></duration>
<duration><code>12</code>
<label>12 Months</label></duration>
<duration><code>3</code>
<label>03 Months</label>
</duration><duration>
<code>6</code>
<label>06 Months</label></duration>
</durationsList><optionsList/>
</offer><offer>
<code>REACFEE|REACFEE</code>
<label>Reactivation Freemium DTH</label><durationsList>
<duration><code>12</code><label>12 Months</label>
</duration></durationsList><optionsList/></offer></offersList>
</CheckAccountReturn>
```

As you can see there are multiple values under **offerslist** and under each offer we have a offer code,duration code And I want to collect the codes into dict like [{" RACCS19|RACCS19":[1,12,3,6],"RBASS18|RBASS18"": [1,12,3,6], "REACFEE|REACFEE": [12] }]

As per my approach i tried with this:

```
new_sanitized_data = bs(xml_data, 'xml')
            def parsing_data_for_multiple_values_for_get_optional_offers(values):
                listed_data = []
                for v in values:
                    tags = ['code', 'offer', 'duration', 'offersList']
                    item = {}
                    for tag in tags:
                        print(tag)
                        item[tag] = v.find(tag).text
                    listed_data.append(item)
                return listed_data
    
            listed_record=parsing_data_for_multiple_values_for_get_optional_offers(new_sanitized_data)
```

and the output looks like this:

```
[{'code': 'RACCS19|RACCS19', 'offer': 'RACCS19|RACCS19Renew Shall DTH 2019101 Months1212 Months303 Months606 Months', 'duration': '101 Months', 'offersList': 'RACCS19|RACCS19Renew Shall DTH 2019101 Months1212 Months303 Months606 MonthsRBASS18|RBASS18Renew Htoo Shall DTH 2019101 Months1212 Months303 Months606 MonthsREACFEE|REACFEEReactivation Freemium DTH1212 Months'}]}
```

anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `xml_doc` is your XML snippet from the question, then this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_doc, 'html.parser')

out = {}
for offer in soup.select('offerslist offer'):
    out[offer.code.text] = [c.text for c in offer.select('duration code')]

print(out)
```

Produces:

```
{'RACCS19|RACCS19': ['1', '12', '3', '6'], 
 'RBASS18|RBASS18': ['1', '12', '3', '6'], 
 'REACFEE|REACFEE': ['12']}
```

---

If you have multiple `<offerslist>` in your XML, then:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

out = []
for offerslist in soup.select('offerslist'):
    out.append({})
    for offer in offerslist.select('offer'):
        out[-1][offer.code.text] = [c.text for c in offer.select('duration code')]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[{'RACCS19|RACCS19': ['1', '12', '3', '6'], 'RBASS18|RBASS18': ['1', '12', '3', '6'], 'REACFEE|REACFEE': ['12']}]
```